# Avoid splitting of math expressions in text

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, inline

I am writing a math expression, `$P = \omega \tau$`, in the middle of my text, and LaTeX splits it such that "`P =`" is on one line and "`\omega \tau`" is on the next line. I would like the whole expression to be on the same line. Is there any way to do this in LaTeX? I tried hyphenation, but that only works for words...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's clearly a duplicate. My advice is to wait until the document is in final form for tackling these problems. And to add `\nolinebreak` after `=` in the cases you don't want a break. Enclosing the formula in braces is not the best way, because this freezes spacing, disallowing it to participate in stretching/shrinking spaces for justification.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{}`: `${P = \omega \tau}$`, but then overfull hboxes can appear.